# Qt mouse co-ordinates on Label

Tags: c++, qt

Hi I need to draw a rectangle over Qlabel, as a first step I am trying to get the mouse events. Using below code the event get called but the co-ordinates are always same even if I changed the mouse position.

Also I need to set the mouse tracking only on the Qlabel, and it's working fine except the mouse release, the function `mouseReleaseEvent` getting called when the mouse released outside the Qlabel.

Also please see the comments in the below code,

```
ImageEditer::ImageEditer(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::ImageEditer)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->label_image->setMouseTracking(true); // need to set the mouse tracking over this label
}

void ImageEditer::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
  qDebug() << "Mouse move.." << pos() << "---> " << x() << "," << y(); // these printing same values
}

void ImageEditer::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
  qDebug() << "Mouse press.." << pos() << "---> " << x() << "," << y(); // these printing same values
}

// This getting called when release the mouse outside the  label_image
void ImageEditer::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "Mouse release.." << pos() << "---> " << x() << "," << y(); // these printing same values
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing pos(), x(), y() of the widget.
Just change it to event->pos(), event->pos().x(), event->pos().y()

Comment: You are right, my silly mistake, and do you have any idea about `mouseReleaseEvent ` getting called while releasing mouse outside the Qlabel.

Comment: What I know that when you press and hold then the widget will become "target" until you release it. But to skip it, in release event you can simply check if the pos is outside of widget geometry.

Comment: Just as a reminder: If you need the global pos of the mouse you can use `event->globalPos()`. Depending on your needs this might be more suitable.